# Code downloads a text file from a website, saves it to local disk, and then loads it into a list for further processing

Tags: python, array, file

My program opens a website and downloads a text file.  The text file is a simple file with one word per line. I save the file to local disk and then create a list to hold each line of the text file for later processing.  I would like to know if I am doing these first steps in a way that would be considered idiomatic Python and have I made any big mistakes that will hamper my efforts to expand on it later.

This is similar to an exercise in Think Python by Allen Downey.  He suggests using a browser to download the text file but I wanted to do it with Python.

```
import requests

def get_webpage(uri):
    return requests.get(uri)


def save_webpagecontent(r, filename):
    """ This function saves the page retrieved by get_webpage. r is the 
    response from the call to requests.get and
    filename is where we want to save the file to in the filesystem."""

    chunk_size = 8388608                # number of bytes to write to disk in each chunk
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)


def make_wordlist(filename):
    wordlist = []
    with open(filename) as fd:
        wordlist = fd.readlines()
    return wordlist


def get_mylist(wordlist, num_lines=10):
    if len(wordlist) <= num_lines:
        return wordlist
    return wordlist[:num_lines]


def print_mylist(mylist):
    for word in mylist:
        print(word.strip())
    return None

"""List of words collected and contributed to the public domain by
Grady Ward as part of the Moby lexicon project. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project
"""
uri = 'https://ia802308.us.archive.org/7/items/mobywordlists03201gut/CROSSWD.TXT'
filename = 'wordlist.txt'

r = get_webpage(uri)
save_webpagecontent(r, filename)
wordlist = make_wordlist(filename)
mylist = get_mylist(wordlist)
print_mylist(mylist)
```

My program works as I expect it to.  I have basically found how to do each individual piece by reading this forum and but I would like to know if I'm putting all the pieces together correctly.  By correctly I mean something that not only functions as expected but also will be easy to build larger programs and modules from.

I hope it isn't wrong of me to post this much code.  I wasn't sure how I could trim it down and still show what I am doing.  Please let me know if I need to change the format of my question.

Comment: Your code looks good, and it is not really long. Here on Code Review it is accepted to sometimes post around 1000 lines, if that's necessary for understanding the code. When pasting your code, you made a small mistake with the indentation around the `chunk_size` line. After you repaired this, your question is in a perfect format for this site, especially since you explained in detail what code you wrote and why. That's something essential that several other questions are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks.  I feel more encouraged about the process now!

Comment: Don't worry, the SE network can be confusing for new users. You're in The Good Place now.

Comment: Might want to add an event in case the request can't be completed and you can't download the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is nice and concise however there are some changes you can make:

1. You can just return `f.readlines()` in `make_wordlist`.
2. If you've done this to show that the result is a list then it'd be better to use the `typing` module.

   ```
   from typing import List


   def make_wordlist(filename: str) -> List[str]:
       ...
   ```
3. `get_mylist` can be replaced with `wordlist[:numlines]`. This is because if `len(wordlist)` is smaller or equal to `numlines`, then it will return the entire thing anyway.
4. Performance wise it's best to use `print('\n'.join(list))` rather than `for item in list: print(item)`.
5. I would prefer to be able to change `chunk_size` in `save_webpagecontent` and so you can make it a default argument.
6. IIRC multi-line docstrings shouldn't start on the same line as the `"""`, nor should they end on the same line either.

```
import requests
from typing import List

Response = requests.Response


def get_webpage(uri) -> Response:
    return requests.get(uri)


def save_webpagecontent(r: Response, filename: str,
                        chunk_size: int=8388608) -> None:
    """
    This function saves the page retrieved by get_webpage. r is the 
    response from the call to requests.get and
    filename is where we want to save the file to in the filesystem.
    """
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)


def read_wordlist(filename: str) -> List[str]:
    with open(filename) as fd:
        return fd.readlines()


def print_mylist(word_list: List[str]) -> None:
    print('\n'.join(word.strip() for word in word_list))


"""
List of words collected and contributed to the public domain by
Grady Ward as part of the Moby lexicon project. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Project
"""
uri = 'https://ia802308.us.archive.org/7/items/mobywordlists03201gut/CROSSWD.TXT'
filename = 'wordlist.txt'

r = get_webpage(uri)
save_webpagecontent(r, filename)
print_mylist(read_wordlist(filename)[:10])
```

Comment: `requests.get()` returns a `Response` object, not a `Request`.

Comment: @LukaszSalitra Thank you, I've updated the code with that. Thought I read the docs correctly :/

Comment: As per [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings) multi-line docstrings can start either right after the opening `"""` or on the line below.

Comment: Thank you for your review.  So is type hinting (I think that's what it's called) the defacto Pythonic way now?  I have to admit that now that I know what the syntax means it does seem really easy to look at a function and know how to use it.  Readability is reason enough to start using it but I am also wondering if Python uses to make code safer or more efficient?  Again, thanks for the review and tips.

Comment: @DuaneWhitty It's 100% optional. They don't make the code faster. If you use one of mypy, pyright, pyre or pytype then they can perform static code analysis which should make your code safer.

Comment: print_mylist(read_wordlist(filename)[:10])

If I am understanding this correctly what is happening is that make_wordlist() and get_mylist have been replaced by one function, read_wordlist(), which all in one go opens the file and returns a list.  Then we pass a slice of that list to the print_mylist() function.  No intermediary functions or variables involved.  So to make concrete my takeaway, regardless of how an object is delivered, whether assigned to a variable name or not, the object is the same.  So,

    read_wordlist(filename)[:10]

is the same as wordlist[:10].  That's cool!

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of my comment.  I've tried to fix it twice but I seem not to be doing the code block mode or blank lines correctly

Comment: @DuaneWhitty No problem to use `this text` you need to write \`this text\`. Feel free to try that out here. You also can't put newlines in comments. (They would look like a mess) Yeah looks like you're correct.

Comment: Thanks.  So I was trying to get this effect `print_mylist(read_wordlist(filename)[:10])`

Answer (score 3):

Your program is concise and well-readable. One thing that is probably less pythonic is storing the received data in a file. If you have no further use for the file, you could just process the data into a wordlist while receiving it. This saves one intermediate step, and your program would not leave a residual `wordlist.txt` file around.

Comment: Besides the gains mentioned, file I/O is expensive CPU-wise. However, it's unclear at the moment whether the further processing of the words (*"and then create a list to hold each line of the text file for later processing"*) is going to be done by the same Python program or a different program altogether. Saving to file as an intermediary step for safety/redundancy/whatever reasons is still a good reason to keep it around.

Comment: Thank you both.  I saved the file for two reasons: 1) I knew that I would want to be accessing the file many times over and over to try different analysis techniques as my knowledge grows.  I'll be running word length analysis and letter frequency analysis and then trying out different ways to display the results.  I thought it would be more efficient that downloading it many times over and over and also more polite to the site I'm downloading from.  2) I am thinking about how I should write programs in case I have less than ideal network conditions.  Thanks again!

Comment: One way to download the file only once would be to check for its existence and only download it if the file is not present. That's basically a simple cache without an invalidation policy, and you can manually invalidate the cache by removing the file. Alternatively, you could write separate download and analysis programs, which would help to avoid code duplication with the associated risk of having slightly different versions of the download code in each program.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the reviews.  I have made some big updates to my code using the suggestions I received here.  Should I now open another request for a code review or should I answer my question with my updated code?  The changes include splitting the file handling into another module and using contextmanager to handle file not found errors.

Answer (score 1):

Code downloads a text file from a website, saves it to local disk, and then loads it into a list for further processing - Version 2.0

In my new version of this code I have separated my code into 3 modules (my start at a 12 factor app):

`download.py` for handling downloading the text file from the website and saving it as a file to local storage;

`config.py` for specifying the URI of the website and the filename for local storage;

`moby.py` is the actual code that reads the words in the text file, 1 per line, into a list.  For now all it does is prints out the words from the file, one per line.

The review my code received provided valuable suggestions on how it could be made more Pythonic, more modular, and more efficient.

Motivated by [Hans-Martin Mosner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/190512/hans-martin-mosner) to separate the file download code here is that module.  Also made the chunk_size a parameter to the save_webpagecontent() function based on as suggested by [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz)

**download.py**

```
import requests
from typing import List

Response = requests.Response

def get_webpage(uri) -> Response:
    return requests.get(uri)


def save_webpagecontent(r: Response, filename: str, chunk_size=8388608) -> None:
    """
    This function saves the page retrieved by get_webpage.
    r is the response from the call to requests.get.
    filename is where we want to save the file to in the filesystem.
    chunk_size is the number of bytes to write to disk in each chunk
    """

    with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

**config.py**

```
uri = 'https://ia802308.us.archive.org/7/items/mobywordlists03201gut/CROSSWD.TXT'
filename = 'wordlist.txt'
```

I feel I made the most gains in my Python profiency as a result of implementing the changes suggested by [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) where I did away with intermediate function calls and variables and by working on the suggestion by [BruceWayne](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/92133/brucewayne) to add an event for failing to open the file.  The file opening code turned out to be the most challenging.  I wasn't able to get `opened_w_error() working exactly based on the example from [PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).  Figuring it out was very rewarding.

**moby.py**

```
import download_file as df
import config as cfg
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import List

filename = cfg.filename
uri = cfg.uri

@contextmanager
def opened_w_error(filename, mode="r"):
    try:
        f = open(filename, mode)
    except OSError as err:
        yield None, err
    else:
        try:
            yield f, None
        finally:
            f.close()


def read_wordlist(filename: str) -> List[str]:
    with opened_w_error(filename, 'r') as (fd, err):
        if type(err) == FileNotFoundError:
            df.save_webpagecontent(df.get_webpage(uri), filename) #since it failed the first time we need to actually download it
            with opened_w_error(filename, 'r') as (fd, err): # if it fails again abort
                if err:
                    print("OSError:", err)
                else:
                    return fd.readlines()
        else:
            return fd.readlines()


def print_mylist(wordlist: List[str]) -> None:
    print('\n'.join(word.strip() for word in wordlist))


print_mylist(read_wordlist(filename)[:50])
```

Thank you to everyone, especially [Roland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6499/roland-illig), [Hans-Martin Mosner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/190512/hans-martin-mosner), and [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) for all your help and encouragement and a safe place to learn!